# Python HTML Parser and Navigator

Tags: python, html, dom, tree-traversal

It's been a long while since I've worked with Python and I'm working on a small project where I need to be able to essentially locate an element as well as traverse the tree. Below is a JavaScript snippet of what I need to be able to do in Python.

I should note that I want to read the HTML from a webpage then get to the below. Getting and reading the HTML from a webpage, I can do, just not traversal.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ic.ic_notice2').forEach(function(v,i) {
    var info = v.nextElementSibling.children[0];
    var id = info.href.replace(patt, "$2");
    if (done.indexOf(id) == -1) {
        done.push(id);
        console.log(info.textContent);
    }
});
```

Without giving me full code, can someone point me towards a library that can help me achieve this? Examples are appreciated but not necessary.
Thanks.

Comment: [xml.dom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html)?

Comment: @kvorobiev As far as I can tell, that only allows to create documents. I'm trying to read HTML from a webpage and traverse that.

Comment: Look at docs of pandas they support different parsers and describe pros and cons of each http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#html-table-parsing

Answer (score 1):

You can try the library **'BeautifulSoup'** to parse the HTML response. You can go through this file, which is just a sample for traversing a HTML response
https://github.com/shiva1791/Python_webcrawler/blob/master/webcrawler.py

Answer (score 0):

I have used Beautiful soup and know for sure that you cannot traverse script or noscript. Try this:
https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/